# Disabling Physical Keyboard in Android Tablet

Tags: android, keyboard

Ok so i bought Chinese tablet and chinese Keyboard which drains my tab battery v.fast, so
i am thinking to create an app to enable and disable physical keyboard, can any one help me for how i can target physical keyboard in codings, or is there any other possible way.

EDIT: by Disable i mean no interaction in any sense with physical keyboard, or say disable usb port, what you'll suggest

I also have ROM toolbox, which also allows me to play with some of the build properties so if u can help me in this way than i will be very thankful b/c it will save me alot time.

Android: 4.0.3
keyboards connects with usb cable.

anyway Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway i would like to share my solution,

I enabled Pin Lock and it turns android into sleep mode, so after a little time my physical keyboard gets disabled automatically, (capslock light stops responding).

;)